# Can Calendar show schedules for indiviual cases?

Tags: solspace-calendar

My client's site needs to show the tutoring schedule for an individual student selected from a list (only one calendar/student at a time).

So if I have Calendar taking the input on the back end in my channel for each student, can I display it on the front end for the selected student?

Also, is Calendar a channel field?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Calendar is not simply a channel field. Calendar is a module which, upon installation, creates two channels: **Calendar: Calendars**, to hold Calendar data, and **Calendar: Events**, which are event data created under a selected Calendar (created in Calendar: Calendars). Similarly named custom field groups are also created. Both channels contain specialized Calendar custom fields.

> **Important: You MUST use the channels and custom field groups provided by Calendar upon installation**
>
> You cannot create another channel to hold Calendar data, nor can you create another custom field group for the Calendar channels, nor can you move/use the special Calendar custom fields to another custom field group.

A good strategy would be to create 1 calendar per student. You would therefore have a **Calendar: Calendars** entry for each student. On the front-end, many Calendar tags have a `calendar_id=""` or `calendar_name=""` parameter that you can use to display event data for a single Calendar (or Student in your case).

Comment: OK so far so good. :)

But one important feature of the website is only tutors assigned to the students - and the schools that the students belong to - can see the students' schedules (for privacy reasons).

This was accomplished by using the author tags (for the tutors making the schedules) + a Playa relationship to the schools. 

Can it be expected that this feature can be retained somehow if Calendar is used? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: When creating an event, the Calendar widget has a dropdown which contains _all_ Calendars. Unfortunately it's not possible to remove some of these calendars from the widget's dropdown, so any tutor would be able to select any "individual student" calendar when creating events. Displaying events is another story: on the front-end you could display only events (Calendar: Events channel) that have been authored by the currently logged in tutor (see http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/calendar/#author_id).

Comment: For schools, you could either have a Playa/Relationship field in your "Schools" channel pointing to event entries in "Calendar: Events", or the other way around: a 
Playa/Relationship field in your "Calendar: Events" channel pointing to a "School" channel entry. Then again, if your tutor is already linked somehow to a school, maybe you can retrieve the school based on the tutor. It really depends on your setup; there are likely more than one way to setup all of this up, but the current answer is the only requirement: you _must_ use the channels/fields provided by Calendar.